How can I create interaction plots for categorical predictors of a gbm.step object in dismo?
I am attempting to use the dismo package to make interaction plots for my model. Other examples (such as this thread) give great tutorials for continuous predictors but I cannot understand how to even extract the interaction values for the different levels of my factors.
Here is an example of the code:
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(dismo)

data(penguins)
ex_df = penguins %>% 
  select(1,2,7,6) %>% 
  mutate(body_mass_g = as.numeric(body_mass_g)) %>% 
  drop_na()
  
ex_gbm = gbm.step(data = data.frame(ex_df), gbm.x = 1:3, gbm.y = 4, family = "gaussian", step.size = 1,
                               learning.rate = 0.0005, bag.fraction = 0.6, tree.complexity = 2)

gbm.perspec(ex_gbm, x = 1, y= 2)

When attempting to use the gbm.perspec() function I continue to get the error:
"Error in gbm.perspec(best_model, x = 1, y = 2) :
at least one marginal predictor must be a vector!"
I would love to output a heat map of predictor interactions if possible!
